# IntegrationFlows having filter on Error Channel

Tags: spring-integration, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have the below code which accepts only the message of type of 'shipment'. Basically the MQ topic accepts two types of messages 'order' and 'shipment'.

Below logic works fine as long as I receive 'shipment' messages but it will throw an error through errorChannel if the topic receives an invalid 'order' payload since I have placed the filter after .errorChannel().

My question is, is there anyway I can place .filter() before the .errorChannel()? I do not care for other message types apart from 'shipment' type.

Thanks in advance.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow jmsInboundFlow() throws Exception {
return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(messageListenerContainer)
        .errorChannel(inboundErrorChannel))
        .filter(Message.class, m -> m.getHeaders().get("message_type").equals("shipment"))
        .channel(routerChannel)
        .get();
}
```

**EDIT**:
The errorChannel() works fine if the payload is null or invalid, but the problem here is it is throwing on other message type as well which I am not interested.

Error message I got on 'order' message type:

```
FailedMessage: GenericMessage [payload=<order></order>, headers={...}

org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: 
error occurred in message handler [bean 'jmsInboundFlow.filter#0' for component 'jmsInboundFlow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0';

org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [bean 'jmsInboundFlow.filter#0' for component 'jmsInboundFlow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/win/managedinventorysubscriber/sicomponent/MsgDrivenChannelAdapter.class]'; from source: 'bean method jmsInboundFlow']; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=<order></order>, headers={JMS_IBM_Character_Set=IBM037, JMS_IBM_MsgType=8, sales_order_guid=421028b0-a09d-41e3-878c-f6ce0163e18d, sales_order_action_code=delete, jms_destination=topic:///WISE/ORDERSHIPMENT, sales_order_company_nbr=00028, JMSXUserID=qmqmuser    , JMS_IBM_Encoding=273, message_type=order, priority=0, jms_timestamp=1643727671960, JMSXAppID=T1WSERVICEQA                , JMS_IBM_PutApplType=26, JMS_IBM_Format=MQSTR   , jms_redelivered=false, JMS_IBM_PutDate=20220201, JMSXDeliveryCount=1, sales_order_nbr=007265, jms_correlationId=ID:414d5120543157534552564943455141a290cb6009df8425, JMS_IBM_PutTime=15011196, id=2ea81c40-ce4e-990c-aba7-961c4b464304, jms_messageId=ID:414d5120543157534552564943455141a290cb6000838d25, timestamp=1643727671913}]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:192)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:65)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:151)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.send(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:428)
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener$GatewayDelegate.send(ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.java:509)
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.onMessage(ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.java:345)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:744)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:704)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:318)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:257)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1165)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1062)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.win.managedinventorysubscriber.sicomponent.MsgDrivenChannelAdapter.lambda$jmsInboundFlow$0(MsgDrivenChannelAdapter.java:33)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.LambdaMessageProcessor.processMessage(LambdaMessageProcessor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.filter.AbstractMessageProcessingSelector.accept(AbstractMessageProcessingSelector.java:65)
    at org.springframework.integration.filter.MessageFilter.doHandleRequestMessage(MessageFilter.java:171)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingPostProcessingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(AbstractReplyProducingPostProcessingMessageHandler.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:134)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `filter` by itself is enough if you just want to ignore.

```
public class MessageFilter extends AbstractReplyProducingPostProcessingMessageHandler
        implements DiscardingMessageHandler, ManageableLifecycle {

    private final MessageSelector selector;

    private boolean throwExceptionOnRejection;

    private MessageChannel discardChannel;

    private String discardChannelName;
```

The `selector` is your function to decide on the incoming message.

The `throwExceptionOnRejection` is false by default, so no exception is thrown is message does not satisfy the filter.

The `discardChannel` is `null` by default, so no any rejection is sent when message does not satisfy the filter.

Therefore the filter in your configuration is not a root cause of that exception. Please, share more info about an exception in your question.

See its docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#filter

Comment: updated the description

Comment: Can we see the whole stack trace? I only can guess that your filter function is wrong for the message. Probably there is just no that `message_type` in the incoming message...

Comment: added the stack trace, thanks

Comment: No, I mean there has to be more after that `MessageHandlingException`, with something like `cause by`.

Comment: I see what you saying, its throwing a null pointer exception in the filter logic since header 'source_System' is missing in there (updated the stacktrace above)